# Unity: Third Person Collision with Animated Platforms

Tags: unity-game-engine

first time posting on stack and everything looks promising so far! I had a bit of a complicated question here so I'll do my best to provide exact details of what I'd like to get accomplished. I'm working with a third person controller in unity, so far everything is going great. I've dabbled with basic up and down platforms, a little glitchy but things work. Anytime my player runs through a mesh I make sure the mesh collider is working and a 'rigid-body' is attached set to Kinematic. Here's the kicker, in my game I have turning gears which the player can jump on. This is great except for the player doesn't turn with my gear, which would make sense according to my game-play. What would be the process for getting my character to interact with this animated mesh? I imagine some sort of script which my nooby mind cannot fathom at this point in my unity career. If anyone out there knows the solution to this, I would love to have any assistance, either way I'll plugging away at a solution. Thanks again!!

Comment: Hopefully you've already posted this question on _Unity Answers_ where you're sure to get a quicker response...

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming that you're using the packages that ship with Unity3D, which it sounds like you are. After importing the **Character Controllers** package, you'll have a bunch of scripts in the *Standard Assets\Character Controllers\Sources\Scripts* folder, in the project hierarchy view. There's a script in there called **CharacterMotor.js**, attach that to the same GameObject you're running ThirdPersonController on.

Essentially this script adds more interactivity between the character and the scene. There's several methods inside this script that automatically move the character when in contact with a moving object (as long as it has a collision mesh) basically by inheriting the object's velocity.

If your gear/cog wheel has a proper collision mesh set up, adding this script to your character should be all that you require.